# Show blank cell using IF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple *IF* formula in a cell that refers to a date in another cell.

Basically an enquiry register which I want to show **"On Time"** or **"Late"** or **"Ongoing"**, but if there is a blank cell I want the IF formula cell to also be blank.

I then tried a few variations after endless searching and tried:

```
IF(X281>D281,"Late",IF(X281<D281,"On Time",""))
```

This actually works reasonably well, but if the the 2 dates are the same it displays late yet if I use less than or equal to it displays on time when the cell is blank.

Is there are way that the cell can remain blank if the reference cell is blank?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF(X281="", " ", IF(X281<D281, "On Time", IF(X281=D281, "On Time", IF(X281>D281, "Late", " "))))
```

This formula starts with:

- If blank then return a blank response.
- If earlier than the target date then return an "On Time" response.
- If same as the target date then return an "On Time" response.
- If later than the target date then return a "Late" response

Comment: That actually works perfectly, Thanks you very much!!!!!!!!

Comment: No hassle, Brian.